# Running Ajax request inside .each loop one after another

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to find a way to run each Ajax post request one after another but waiting for the one beforehand to complete before running the next. I've tried a couple of methods to no avail so I've stripped it back down to the basics and am wondering that the best way (and a way that works) to go about this is.

When they are run as they do now, some of the requests never make it through because it seems to be interrupted by the next request.

```
$('.element').each(function() {
        e_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $.ajax({
            url: '/?cart-add=' + e_id +'&quantity=1',
            type: 'POST'
        });
    });
)};
```

Then once that is completed in full I was redirecting to another page which was working correctly but the above requests were an issue as not all items were showing up yet as it went through each iteration it was logging the id to console which were as expected.

```
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

Comment: Set `async: false` in your ajax-options or call `.next()` element in your `success function from $.ajax()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These Ajax Requests run asynchronously so as to improve the user experience.

So perhaps what you will want to do is only call the next Ajax Request once the previous one has completed.

You can specify the function within the "success" option of the ajax call. And with a different way of iterating:

```
var elementArray;
function callingFunction()
{
    elementArray = new Array();
    $(".element").each(function () {
        elementArray.push($(this));
    });
    doAjax(0);

}


function doAjax(arrCount) 
{
    //USE arrCount to access your data
    var e_id = elementArray[arrCount].attr("data-id");
    $.ajax({
        url: "...",
        type:"POST",
        success: function () {
            arrCount++;
            if (arrCount < elementArray.length)
            {
                doAjax(arrCount);
            }
            else
            {
                window.location.href = "......";
            }              
        }
    });
}
```

## Explanation

You place all of your elements within an array (Global Array) start the doAjax function with a zero value. (You should build logic to check whether there are array elements)

When the ajax function completes it checks if there are more items to be sent and calls the doAjax again with the incremented counter.

If there are no more elments, a redirect is done.

### NOTE

It is worth noting that you would rather do one bulk Post with JSON or something rather than doing many little posts.

Hope it helps. Happy Coding.

Comment: This is great, I had tried something similar earlier on but wasn't doing the count. I would use a bulk JSON post if it allowed it but unfortunately I can't modify the other code.

Thanks!

Comment: I know what you mean. I've had to modify code and sometimes you need to workaround other people's stuff. Another comment - when making a commercial site - is you will want to handle the "error" option of the .ajax({}). Just to be sure whatever avenue is taken, you're system doesn't break.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `async: false`in your ajax options object.

**Fiddle:** `jsfiddle.net/pleinx/nhspycf0/`

If something failed in (no data-id or request) will stop the loop.

The other way has already good explain the user `Terrance00`

Comment: This is also a solution - which I have used before - The problem with it is though, it freezes the page (Atleast on Chrome). I have found the better solution is just to correctly handle the asynchronous nature of JS - to get the best experience to the customer :)

Comment: yeah of course user experience are important. i would only show what is possible and the user`Terrance00` was quicker and shows already the option1 :)

Only a information for me: with how much elements you have problems with freezing page?

Comment: The place where I experienced this problem was actually just a single post and South African Internet. The post was offsite though - to Google Maps, depending on the Net Speed I got about a 1 - 2 second delay.